# Add Navigation Menu To Empty Magento CMS Page?

Tags: php, magento

I have an empty magento CMS page, literally nothing on it.

The reason why I need an empty page is because the theme installed has a fixed width, whereas I want to use the entire width of the page for a unique design.

The only problem I have is the fact that the navigation menu is not added by default when I select an empty CMS page. Also, if I simply copy and paste the nav menu from another page, the shopping basket does not update on the empty CMS page, but I need it to.

How do I add the theme's navigation menu to the CMS page?

Comment: Ben, can you share the site you are working on and the url's in question.  I will be glad to help, but I think you are going at it wrong.

Comment: Hi rob, I can't share the site, but I can tell you it currently uses this theme: http://8theme.com/demo/blanco/ As you can see, the columnar layout is centered, whereas I want to add creative content that uses the full width of the users screen. The only way I can go about this is by adding an empty CMS page... Is there a hook where I can just say {{navigation_bar}} or something?

Answer (score 0):

Ben,

There are a few different ways to approach this. Is this unique CMS page the home page?

Option 1:

Set the CMS page to use a new 1column-custom layout where you can move the main blocks around to your hearts content.

To prove if this will work go into template/page/1column.phtml I am assuming you are looking to restructure the one column layout. Make a backup of the original file first and see if you can manipulate the .phtml file to get your desired result on the page you are working on..  If so, take your changes and place them into a new file named 1column-custom.phtml.

Then in the admin panel in the design update section of the desired cms page. You will place in the following code.

```
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column-custom.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

Option 2:

Use a local.xml layout update to set the content block within the home page to your own template.

From the sounds of it option 1 would be more efficient.